# OpenSSL Pads Keys in AES encryption?

Tags: openssh, aes

I posted this on Stack Overflow but someone told me I should post it here instead.

I'm trying to use aes-128-cbc encryption with openssl, and I would expect that the key needs to be 32 digits. However, I noticed that when I put in a key length of 18, openssl does not give me an error.

```
echo hello | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -A -a -nosalt -K 123456789012345678 -iv 66666666666666666666666666666666

output:zBN+65infn74QK+prfY6kw==
```

But if I add 0's after the key until it's 32 digits, I still get the same result.

```
echo hello | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -A -a -nosalt -K 12345678901234567800000000000000 -iv 6666666666666666666666666666666

output:zBN+65infn74QK+prfY6kw==
```

Is there documentation anywhere that says OpenSSL adds padding to keys?